# Google reCaptcha test with Postman

Tags: java, recaptcha

I am creating a backend endpoint to handle user login. Part of the login is a Google [reCaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/about/).

[image]

I am also creating Postman collections to test the backed api's. I have the following:

**AuthenticationResource.java**

```
@POST
@Path("login")
@ApiOperation(value="Login a user with a username and password and return a jwt")
@ApiResponses({
        @ApiResponse(code=200, message="Success"),
        @ApiResponse(code=404, message="Not Found")
})
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public Response login(@ApiParam(required = true) UserLoginDTO userLogin, @Context HttpServletRequest request)  {
    try {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);

        logger.info("login: "+userLogin.getUsername());
        String username = userLogin.getUsername();
        String passwordPlainText = userLogin.getPassword();
        String clientRemoteAddr = request.getRemoteAddr();

        boolean captchaVerified = VerifyRecaptcha.verify(userLogin.getRecaptcha());
        if (!captchaVerified) {
            logger.severe("Invalid captcha");
            return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("Invalid captcha").build();
        }
```

**VerifyRecaptcha.java**

```
public class VerifyRecaptcha {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(VerifyRecaptcha.class.getName());
    public static final String url = "https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify";
    public static final String secret = "my-seceret-key";
    private final static String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

    public static boolean verify(String gRecaptchaResponse) throws IOException {
        if (gRecaptchaResponse == null || "".equals(gRecaptchaResponse)) {
            return false;
        }

        try{
            URL obj = new URL(url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

            // add reuqest header
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
            con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

            String postParams = "secret=" + secret + "&response="
                    + gRecaptchaResponse;

            // Send post request
            con.setDoOutput(true);
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
            wr.writeBytes(postParams);
            wr.flush();
            wr.close();

            int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
            logger.info("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
            logger.info("Post parameters : " + postParams);
            logger.info("Response Code : " + responseCode);

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();

            // print result
            logger.info(response.toString());

            //parse JSON response and return 'success' value
            JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader(response.toString()));
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonReader.readObject();
            jsonReader.close();

            return jsonObject.getBoolean("success");
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.warning("invalid recaptcha: "+gRecaptchaResponse+". "+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Postman**

```
POST https://localhost:8443/corporateInterface/rest/user/login
```

Body

```
{
    "password": "password",
    "username": "richard",
    "recaptchaResponse": "sitekey"
}
```

**Result**

```
Response Code : 200
{  "success": false,  "error-codes": [    "invalid-input-response"  ]}
Invalid captcha
```

As you can see, the call to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify returns a 200, but success is false.

**Question**

Is it possible to test the reCaptcha with Postman? Or will Google not validate a Postman request?  If so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: captchas are exactly there to verify that an actual user is sitting in front of the website, and not some program which is sending some requests like postman

Answer (score 3):

POST to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify

Set content type header (Content-Type) : `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

In your body you have to set the secret and response keys.

The response value must be obtained beforehand via form submit, to get `$_POST["g-recaptcha-response"];`

Success response :

```
{
    "success": true,
    "challenge_ts": "timestamp of challenge",
    "hostname": "yourhostname"
}
```

Having that the siteverify will return the result of the check as if you were doing the verification

Answer (score 0):

captchas are exactly there to verify that an actual user is sitting in front of the website, **and not some program which is sending some requests like postman** ,So you may no be able to verify it using some program.

Comment: You are wrong here pal, you can add your captcha script in your site, capture the outgoing payload and test it on postman to confirm if the captcha is valid or not